# How do I determine which GNU Info Manual files are available?

Tags: emacs, texinfo

I would like Info manuals on various things, including command line utilities, ruby, git, etc. Does anyone know of a database of them? I would rather not go through Googling each item to try to find a Texinfo or Info file or determine whether there is a tool that can generate such a file from existing documentation or source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Linux based machine, if you do `info emacs` and it opens up emacs' man pages, it means emacs' info pages are not installed on that system.  For a Debian GNU/Linux system, installing emacs23-common-non-dfsg will install emacs23's info pages.  Similarly, gdb-doc for gdb, and so on.  This info can be found on the tool's documentation section of its web pages.

So, AFAIK, there is no central database for all the info pages out there.  One more clue is, it is mostly the GNU tools that have their documentation in info pages.  Not sure if others do it the GNU way.

Answer (score 1):

Use this key combination to check what info is currently available on your system:

> C-h i

Info never got particularly popular and many apps simply don't have any info docs. The only ones that have info for certain are the GNU tools(like Emacs itself). That said many distros strip the info docs from their respective program packages because they consider the format irrelevant. As far as know there is no comprehensive info db online as well.